# ELT() with subquery instead of params

Tags: mysql

Whole query:

```
SELECT NULL, 
ELT( MOD( A.contact_id, (SELECT count(*) FROM  `ak_contact` WHERE  `contact_type_id` = 12) )+1, (SELECT  CONCAT( "'",GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(contact_id  AS CHAR(7)) SEPARATOR "','"),"'"  )  FROM  `ak_contact` WHERE  `contact_type_id` = 12) ) as operator_id,
B.account_id, A.contact_id, A.email
FROM ak_contact A
JOIN ak_accounts B USING (contact_id)
GROUP BY A.email, A.contact_id, B.account_id
ORDER BY A.contact_id DESC
```

the subquery should select one of ids number 10493, 10495,11262,11800,12362,13405, one by one for each row:

```
ELT( MOD( A.contact_id, (SELECT count(*) FROM  `ak_contact` WHERE  `contact_type_id` = 12) )+1, (SELECT  CONCAT( "'",GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(contact_id  AS CHAR(7)) SEPARATOR "','"),"'"  )
#result: ELT(MOD(3333, 5)+1, '10493','10495','11262','11800','12362','13405')
```

The problem is that I can't force to work ELT(A.contact_id, subquery) with subquery.
Or how I can make something like this:

```
ELT(MOD(3333, 5)+1, '10493','10495','11262','11800','12362','13405')
```

inside of the main query

Answer (score 1):

You could use FIND_IN_SET and a subquery that delivers all the values as a comma-separated string '10493,10495,11262,...' using GROUP_CONCAT.

(But be aware that the string size that GROUP_CONCAT can return is limited by server config.)

Comment: Thanks, but viceversa I need get by index some id, like that
ELT(3, '123', '234', '345') = 345

Comment: Why do you need ELT for that? Instead of a subquery that delivers _all_ values just to pick only one of those values by position afterwards, just select the one you want directly, using ORDER BY and LIMIT.

Answer (score 0):

Form MySQL 8 You can use:

```
WITH
cte1 AS (
   SELECT
      (MOD( A.contact_id, (SELECT count(*) FROM  ak_contact WHERE  contact_type_id = 12) )+1)mx,
      B.account_id,
      A.contact_id,
      A.email
   FROM ak_contact A
      INNER JOIN ak_accounts B USING (contact_id)
GROUP BY A.email, A.contact_id, B.account_id
), 
cte2 AS (
   SELECT
      (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ())mx,
      CAST(contact_id  AS CHAR(7))cid
   FROM ak_contact
   WHERE contact_type_id = 12
)
SELECT cte1.*, cte2.*
FROM cte1
LEFT JOIN cte2 ON cte1.mx = cte2.mx
ORDER BY cte1.contact_id DESC;
```